How do I include a PGFplot in the list of figures?
I have the following plot:
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[xlabel=Schrittanzahl $T$, ylabel=Optionspreis in \$, mark size = 0]
        \addplot+[
        scatter
        ]
        table[meta=ma]
        {T_bin_call.dat};
        \addplot+[
        scatter
        ]
        table[meta=ma]
        {T_BS_call.dat};
        \addplot+[
        scatter
        ]
        table[meta=ma]
        {T_am_call.dat};
    \legend{Europäisch (Binomialmodell), Europäisch (Black-Scholes), Amerikanisch}
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

How do I give it a caption and include it in the list of figures? I tried putting it into the usual
\begin{figure}
...
\end{figure}

but I didn't manage to treat the graph the same as a normal figure.

put it in figure and add a \caption, if you got an error you would need to show what you did and what error you got

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
